# Add element in a ng-repeat both view and json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

The issue is I have a ng-repeat which source is a json object.

I have an "Add item" button which is supposed to add a new item to that json object and at the same time is rendered as one item more of the json object.

But this item, since it's a new item which wasn't originally in the json object, has the chance to be removed before saving it as an element more of this json object.

I'm not pretty sure if this is only a controller action or i should perform some action in a directive compile/link function to render the element or for other action.

**The following code is just a reference about what I have in mind:**

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="example.addItem()"></button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in example.jsonobject">
            <p class="check-question">Question: {{item.question}}</p>
            <p class="check-explanatory">Explanatory: {{item.explanatory}}</p>

            <p ng-show="item.newItem === false" class="check-answer">Answer: {{item.answer}}</p>
            <input ng-show="item.newItem === true" class="check-answer" ng-model="item.answer">Answer: {{item.answer}}</input>
            <button ng-show="item.newItem === true" ng-click="example.removeItem()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show the JS, or, better than that, provide a JSFiddle or a Plnkr

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It's just a way to serialize data. Once it's in Javascript, there is no more jsonobject - it's just object. So, why do you think it would work differently than normal?

Comment: @NewDev yeah maybe I misexplained, i would like to know any approach that you would face for this. I know that eventually it's an object. So, I am wondering if you would add the item to the object or if you would also have to treat some stuff in a directive, etc.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to add an object, display in the UI, allow removing it, but only commit later? I'm not sure what you mean by directive here, but you could just keep master and view versions of the object (which I'm guessing is really an array of objects) in the controller. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are right in your assumption, I'm now trying some things if  I find an answer I will post it, meanwhile any help or advices are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

**One way** to solve your question is to have separate arrays for existing (and non-delete-able) items and for new items.

```
$scope.items = jsonobject;
$scope.newItems = [];
$scope.addItem = function(){
   $scope.newItems.push($scope.newItem);
}
```

Then, you add to the new array, which allows for deletion. When you finally "save" - it goes to the master array or committed to a service (or to a jsonobject, as you call it). In the view you iterate with `ng-repeat` over each.

I don't particularly like this approach, since it makes your write your `ng-repeat` twice for almost the same HTML structure.

**Another approach** is to decorate your objects with additional metadata to signify new items. I would avoid changing the actual Model, but rather create a ViewModel representation of the Model with extra metadata.

```
$scope.items = [];
angular.forEach(myService.getData(), 
   function(item){
      $scope.items.push({isNew: false, item: item});
   });

$scope.addItem = function(){
   $scope.items.push(
        { isNew: true, 
          item: $scope.newItem // $scope.newItem is set by the input fields
        }); 
}
```

In this case, you only do a single `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div>Question: {{item.item.q}}</div>
  <div>Answer: {{item.item.a}}</div>
  <button ng-if="item.isNew">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/21LrdFMluG8uLrAYSmab?p=preview) with both approaches.